# Merge PDF to ePub

Tags: productivity

I have multiple PDF of my lecture notes and was hoping to convert these to ePub format where the name of the PDF forms an entry on the contents page. I want to do this because I think ePub will be a smaller format and if I can get it below 50mb I can upload it to Google Play Books. It is essentially a lot of presentations in PDF format, where I presume the pictures accounts for the large collective size.

I am not sure if this is the right section, please forward me to the right section if this isn't it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), it converts files to and from various formats, including PDF and EPUB.

Another option is [OxGarage](http://www.tei-c.org/oxgarage/). That won't require an install of software.

If those don't create the result you want, and you're willing to spend some time on it: you may choose to export your PDF to HTML, then re-piece your document together in [Sigil Epub Creator](https://sigil-ebook.com/)

The export and reformat in Sigil would take time to master, but it's a good skill to have if it's likely you'll be doing this transformation more than a few times.

**UPDATE (2016):** Add [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) and [Poppler (Linux only)](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to the list of options. Anyone who is working with PDF content will need patience and many options. PDF encoding is complex and varied. I usually have to go through three tools to get a result that is workable.