# How to properly convert a PDF to Mobi with Calibre?

Tags: pdf, mobi

I know how to convert PDFs using calibre the simple way. Just pressing convert and thats's it.
But how can I actually convert the PDF to a "richer" .mobi?

I would like to take the images, headline formarts and mathematical expressions of texts as well after the conversion. But what do I need to do for that?

Answer (score 21):

You do not need any software for that. You can just use your device email service to convert. Plus, I think Kindle email convert service is more successful than the Calibre in converting multi-column Pdf's.

How to do: Just email one pfd file to your Kindle mail account -namesurname@kindle.com- (every kindle owner has such an email address given by Amazon, you could find in your device "Settings - Device Options - Personalise Your Kindle - Send-to-Kindle E-mail").

Note that: [The subject of the email needs to be "Convert"](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/email)

Otherwise: It is not converted and placed in your device as a pdf file.

Comment: It might be a good idea if you provided a reference to Amazon documentation for your answer.

Comment: Not always easy. WHen you have a PDF of a great size, sending it via mail is not a good solution.

Answer (score 12):

I do not think that this is possible using calibre. Handling images maybe somehow be possible, but since mathematical expressions are usually stored as text they will likely be screwed up by any conversion efforts.

Instead I would suggest you take a look at [k2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/). This allows you to generate a new PDF optimized for your reader's display size.

It can handle multiple columns, resize and reflow text, preserve images and formulas. Tables are often preserved as well, but stay small. Just try it, maybe it works for you.

If you like the results and do not mind jailbreaking your Kindle, you can run the program directly on it. I give some more details on this in [this](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/137/118) answer on StackExchange's ebook site.

Answer (score 0):

I replied to a similar Q earlier. [Merge PDF to ePub](https://superuser.com/questions/691548/merge-pdf-to-epub/702498#702498).

After you create an EPUB, you would need to use [Kindle Previewer](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765261) to turn it into mobi and eventually load it onto a Kindle.

Your task may be easy, or laborious, depending on the internals of your PDF file. That is dependent on "how" the PDF was created in the first place, which might not have been under your control.

From my experience, if the PDF was created from a scanned document, you'll have to do quite a bit of review and manual editing, which doesn't meet your desire for the 'simple way.'